# draw a background color for a UILabel frame where text is present'

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm trying to figure out a way to get a background color of a UILabel to draw only where text is present.  I'm planning to use **`drawTextInRect`**, but i need to figure out how to track the text bounds

```
- (void) drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
 /* do some custom drawings here */

 [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

[image]

does anyone have any idea how to get this done? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attributed string in your label:

```
NSAttributedString * text =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"This is a tring"
                               attributes:@{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor]}];
_label.attributedText = text;
```

If you want it to be transparent, set alpha value of the color < 1. You should also set opaque to NO.

```
NSAttributedString * text =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"This is a tring."
                               attributes:@{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.2]}];
_label.opaque = NO;
_label.attributedText = text;
```

Comment: thank you so much. i know this is off topic but do you know if i can set the opacity for the background color as well?